# QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: . near

Tags: java, hibernate

Este é o erro acredito que é facil pra quem manja de Java mas como eu estou aprendendo ainda não identifiquei o problema.

```
GRAVE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: . near line 1, column 49 [select c from com.htcursos.model.entity.Cidade c.estado=:est]
```

Aqui esta meu CidadeDAO.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Cidade> buscarCidades(Estado estado) {
    Query consulta = em.createQuery("select c from Cidade c.estado=:est");//JPQL
    consulta.setParameter("est", estado);
    return consulta.getResultList();
}
```

Se isso não bastar pra solucionar o problema me peçam mais informações que adiciono ao post.
Todo a ajuda é muita apreciada então Obrigado desde já.

UPDATE:
Erro após WHERE inserido:

```
GRAVE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [c.estado], unexpected token [c] [select c from com.htcursos.model.entity.Cidade where c.estado=:est]
```

Tabelas

**Cidade**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Estado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o erro retornado:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   . near line 1, column 49 [select c from
>   com.htcursos.model.entity.Cidade c.estado=:est]

O problema está na sintaxe da *query* (`QuerySyntaxException`), acredito que segundo a sua necessidade você poderia utilizar a *query* abaixo (com o `WHERE`):

```
SELECT c.nome FROM Cidade c WHERE c.estado =:est
```

Coloquei `c.nome` porque acredito que você precisa do nome da cidade.

Comment: coloquei o where mas um outro erro foi apresentado
 org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [c.estado]

Comment: poderia adicionar o outro erro a pergunta?

Comment: @Zuqui poderia adicionar detalhes sobre o banco que você está tentando fazer a consulta?

Comment: A da esquerda é a tabela cidade e da direita estado

Comment: Qual é o objetivo deste método que está implementando (qual dado você quer buscar no banco)?

Comment: quero buscar a cidade que tem o estado_id igual o id da tabela estado.

Comment: @Zuqui atualizei a resposta

Comment: @Zuqui, alterei a query. Tente com esta, caso não funcione me responda aqui.

Comment: Oi williamhk2 funcionou sim muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Sua query está errada, falta a palavra `where` nela.

```
select c from Cidade where c.estado = :est
```